# Azure Service Bus - autoforwarding message from dead-letter queue to another queue

Tags: azureservicebus

I know how to do autoforwarding from one queue to another but, I need to forward message from dead letter to another regular queue and I'm wondering if I can achieve that without any external application that will fetch those message and send it to queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to forward message from dead letter to another regular queue
> and I'm wondering if I can achieve that without any external
> application that will fetch those message and send it to queue.

Yes, you should be able to achieve it without any external application. When creating/updating a queue, you can specify the name of other queue or topic in the same namespace where dead letter messages will be forwarded automatically.

For example, if you're using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` .Net SDK, you can make use of [`CreateQueueOptions.ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.createqueueoptions.forwarddeadletteredmessagesto?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_Administration_CreateQueueOptions_ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo) property to configure this setting.

You should also be able to use [`New-AzServiceBusQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/new-azservicebusqueue?view=azps-6.4.0) or [`az servicebus queue create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/queue?view=azure-cli-latest#az_servicebus_queue_create) if you don't want to write the code.

Comment: Cool, I see it now! Thank you

Comment: Is any way to add property to message when it's autoforwarding from dead-letter? I would like to add name of the queue during this process.

Comment: @surzyn - It's not possible to do so as this forwarding happens automatically on the service side.